# Ternary operator execution of methods

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have a `HashMap<Foo,ArrayList<Bar>>` and I want that when I get the `ArrayList` associated to a key and add some value to it.

The ternary operator makes

What I'm currently doing is checking if the value associated to the key Foo is null, if it is then make a new ArrayList add what I want to it and put it back into the map. If not, I store they arrayList add what I want to it and again put it back into the map.

I could do it like this:

```
ArrayList<Bar> valuesList = map.get(key);
if(valuesList == null){
    valuesList = new ArrayList<Bar>;
}
valuesList.add(Item);
map.put(Foo,valuesList);
```

But I prefer using the ternary operator to make my code a bit shorter:

```
ArrayList<Bar> valuesList= (map.get(key) == null) ? new ArrayList<Bar>() : map.get(key);
valuesList.add(Item);
map.put(Foo,valuesList);
```

My question is, (in the second) example am I executing `map.get(key)` twice? Or is the Java compiler being smart and evaluating it only once? (I know it's a tiny difference in terms of execution speed but if it's executing twice it's enough of a reason for me to start using example 1)

Comment: Use guava multimap instead: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Comment: you could investigate the bytecode by using `javap -c com.mypackage.MyClass` to see what is happening under the hood.

Comment: So, instead of using a temporary variable for the result of `map.get(key)`, you more likely use the first code instead of your prefered ternary operator?

Comment: If you use Java 8 you can do `map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new)` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is what I'd use, as you also wouldn't unnecessarily call a put if the list is already in your map:

```
List<Bar> valuesList = map.get(key);
if(valuesList == null){
    valuesList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
     map.put(key,valuesList);
}
valuesList.add(Item);
```

Note, I find this much more readable than using the ternary operator (less lines of code is not necessarily simpler, IMHO). And depending on the size of your maps, saving on unnecessary calls (the get and put) may not be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Investigating the bytecode learns that the get() method is actually called twice in your second code snippet. In theory it's possible that the map would change between the calls so this can't be optimized.

On a side note: your call map.put() is redundant, because by modifying the object you will automatically change the stored object in the map. You're not pulling a copy from the map, you're pulling a reference to the object from the map.

Answer (score 1):

Why not passing the map.get(key) in a variable and then use it with ternary operator?

You could do:

```
Object value = map.get(key);
ArrayList<Bar> valuesList = (value == null) ? new ArrayList<Bar>() : value;
valuesList.add(Item);
map.put(Foo,valuesList);
```